# Avoid UEFI Bios Hell?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bios, uefi

It seems so many people are having problems with UEFI these days, i'd be tempted to find hardware that doesn't come with it.

Installing Linux alongside Windows is once again a [real](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) [mess](http://www.ambitious-vision.net/en/fedora-18-and-windows-8-uefi-how-to/). Maybe the technology is young, but if the old bios stuff had its quirks this hardly looks like an improvement. It looks like the EFI partition just made things even more complex and added another point of failure.

What is UEFI buying us exactly ?
Is there any way to opt out ?

All I'm looking for is a simple desktop solution for a Linux / Windows dual boot setup.
I'll gladly ditch Windows 8 if i have to.

Comment: It's dirt simple to dual boot even with UEFI

Comment: Secure boot by the way has NOTHiNG to do with Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is EFI buying us exactly ?

Probably the most obvious and necessary benefit is that EFI understands GPT which is needed for storage devices over 2TB (MBR cannot reach anything beyond the 2TB barrier).

UEFI can actually directly load and run an operating system, like other bootloaders (such as U-Boot), instead of just loading the first LBA of a block device and passing control to it.  Done right it can actually reduce complexity, even though it forces the firmware to understand filesystems - you don't need boot code on your storage device anymore.

Windows doesn't make use of this capability really because Windows uses the same boot files for BIOS or UEFI systems, so the UEFI bootloader just calls the Windows bootloader most of the time.

While Secure Boot, if the end user doesn't have control of the keys, can be used to lock an OS to hardware, if the user is in control of it, it does enhance certain aspects of your computer's security in usual situations.

UEFI also presents a richer environment to pre-boot applications, so it's easier for manufacturers to include diagnostic utilities and such on their boards.

> Is there any way to opt out ?

Some BIOSes have the ability to enable something called CSM - this is the "Compatibility Support Module" and works like the classic BIOS.  Try enabling it if your firmware supports it.

Windows has *always* assumed the only thing you want to run on your computer is other Windows operating systems.  This is not a new problem because of UEFI.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. For the opt out part i was wondering in the case of a windows PC that comes with UEFI if it's possible to revert back to Bios without reinstalling the whole thing. I guess not because of GPT ...